# MongoDB aggregation: average sales per hour

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with sales. Now I need to get the average number of sales per hour within a date range.

Up to now I have a query like this:

```
db.getCollection('sales').aggregate({
    "$match": {
        $and: [
            { "createdAt": { $gte: ISODate("2018-05-01T00:00:00.000Z") } },
            { "createdAt": { $lt: ISODate("2018-10-30T23:59:00.000Z") } },
        ]
    }
},{ 
    "$project": {
      "h":{"$hour":"$createdAt"},
     }
},{ 
     "$group":{ 
        "_id": "$h",
        "salesPerHour": { $sum: 1 },
      },
},{
    "$sort": { "salesPerHour": -1 }
});
```

The result looks like this: {"_id" : 15, "salesPerHour" : 681.0}

How can I get the average value of salesPerHour instead the sum?

**Update 1 => Example document.**

```
{
    "_id" : "pX6jj7j4274J9xpSA",
    "idFiscalSale" : "48",
    "documentYear" : "2018",
    "paymentType" : "cash",
    "cashReceived" : 54,
    "items" : [...],
    "customer" : null,
    "subTotal" : 23.89,
    "taxTotal" : 3.7139,
    "total" : 23.89,
    "rewardPointsValue" : 0,
    "rewardPointsEarned" : 24,
    "discountValue" : 0,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-04-24T00:00:00.201Z")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use below aggregation query.

```
db.sales.aggregate([
  {"$match":{
    "createdAt":{
      "$gte":ISODate("2018-05-01T00:00:00.000Z"), 
      "$lt":ISODate("2018-10-30T23:59:00.000Z")
    }
  }},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":{"$hour":"$createdAt"},
    "salesPerHour":{"$sum":1}
  }},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":null,
    "salesPerHour":{"$avg":"$salesPerHour"}
  }}
])
```

Comment: Anthony it's right. This will return the average of all hours.

Comment: did the answer work for you ? Please consider accepting if it worked,

Comment: Thanks @Veeram but I don't get the expected result.
`{"_id" : null,"salesPerHour" : 339.153846153846}`

Comment: Np what is the expected json output ? Which field has sale value ?

Comment: Something like: `[{"_id" : 8,"salesPerHour" : 11}, {"_id" : 9,"salesPerHour" : 5}, {"_id" : 10,"salesPerHour" : 15},...]`. Where _id is the hour of day. Basically I need to get the avg number of sales for each hour of day.

Comment: Do you have a field which stores sales ? To preform avg you have to know the value of sale at different times within an hour.

Comment: What do you mean with "a field which store sales"? You can see and example doc in the "Update 1" of the question.

Comment: I mean how do you know different value of sales in a hour ? How do you compute it ? What is your criteria ? Once you have list of values you can calculate average for values.

Comment: I'm calculating it within the $group. Each sales made at from 8am to 9am is added with _id:8 and summed to salesPerHour. It's a calculated field, I was thinking that $avg would give me the avarage number of that value. Maybe I'm missing something... :(

Comment: Well there is no average for summed field as it only one value. Other thing if you were to collect all values which is one and you average the those values across the hour the average is always 1. $sum:1 just counts the occurrences of sale.

Comment: You can always get average sales per day by averaging all hourly values interval. Would you want that ?

Comment: Ok now I get it. Thanks again for the explanation! Unluckily the number of sales per day doesn't fit the job, I need it hourly to evaluate opening hours of a store. I'm thinking about creating a temp collection with num_of_sales_per_hour of each day and then calculate the avg.

Answer (score 2):

You can try below aggregation

You have to use [**`$avg`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/) aggregation operator with the `salesPerHour` field

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "$and": [
      { "createdAt": { "$gte": ISODate("2018-05-01T00:00:00.000Z") }},
      { "createdAt": { "$lt": ISODate("2018-10-30T23:59:00.000Z") }}
    ]
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": { "$hour": "$createdAt" },
    "salesPerHour": {
      "$avg": "$salesPerHour"
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: From my aspect it should work but not sure what `salesPerHour` field contains

Comment: `salesPerHour` it's not a collection field. Using your example I get `salesPerHour=null`